# jQuery UI Sliders - Adding values together from different sliders into one value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

This seems like it would be a simple question but I keep running into a wall here.

All I am trying to do is add two values together into one value from two different sliders using jQuery UI.  Here is my current code:

They aren't very clear in the documentation if this can be done or not.  I have tried their methods and still can't get it to do what I want it to.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<script>
$(function() {      

 $("#slider1").slider({
min: 0,
max: 100,
slide: function(event, ui) {
    $('#slider1').slider("option", "value", ui.value);
    var amountOne = $('#amount').val(ui.value);
  }
     });

 $("#slider2").slider({
min: 0,
max: 100,
slide: function(event, ui) {
    $('#slider2').slider("option", "value", ui.value);
    var amountTwo = $('#amount2').val(ui.value);

 }
  });


    });


</script>
```

Here is my HTML

```
 <div id="slider1" style="width:100px"></div>
 <div id="slider2" style="width:100px"></div>

 <input id="amount" />
 <input id="amount2" />
 <input id="amount3" />
```

I just want amount and amount2 to be added together to make amount3.  Seems like it would be easy, but it's been giving me problems.

Comment: You may want to put the `var` statements, which are currently being defined inside the slide function, outside the slide functions - at least if you wish to add them together. Otherwise they will be undefined when outside the functions (I think - logically they would be undefined anyway)

Comment: Sorry I meant define them initially outside - not move the entire lines outside as that would result in `ui.value` being undefined.

Comment: I've tried it..  For some reason it won't give me a value and gives me a object error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out http://jsfiddle.net/ZM59a/2/ - that ought to do it. I just created an update function which is called whenever either of the sliders are moved. Hope it helps.

(PS It was a real pain that applying jQuery UI doesn't automatically include the CSS... I had to check the source at http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ and add the link from there. Got there in the end though :))

Comment: Bravo, exactly what I was looking for.  You are a gentleman and a scholar.

Comment: One question though:  When you click anywhere in the slide, I don't get the correct amount I should have, anyway to remedy this?

Comment: It probably has something to do with padding or something; try Googling it and see if anyone else has had this issue.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the slider values with below code and use them as required.

```
var amountOne = $('#slider1').slider("option", "value");
var amountTwo = $('#slider1').slider("option", "value");
```

Comment: This is no good because the variables aren't global and could only be accessed in their respective functions.

Comment: @SethenMaleno - Don't use the variable, you can directly use `$('#slider1').slider("option", "value")` anywhere in the code.

Comment: Create a function that you attach to all the slider's slide events:  SumSliders() { var amountOne = $('#slider1').slid....  Or, to make it more flexible, in the function, get all the sliders and iterate them and sum the values.